# IBM Domino Directory Assistance with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ibm-domino

I have added an Active Directory Entry  in the Directory Assistance DB.
The command "show xdir" shows the new directory as used.

The users from AD can login to the web server. But I don't know how to specify AD users in the ACL for a DB. 
If I try a page with @UserName, I get only "Name Surname" from the AD user without any other information with the domain or organization name.
I have tried to ass all variants of names without any luck. 
How can I get the right form of user name for a user from AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discussed also here: [Convert Active Directory DistinguishedName to Domino Name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32454449/2487565)

I was able to add users and groups from AD to ACL, by replacing all commas "," in distinguishedName with "/". Of course, the name mapping option have to be set up correctly and Notes distinguished name should be mapped to the distinguishedName field in AD. In your case the notes name should looks like this:

```
CN=Arumugam Barath/OU=Users/OU=Region - North America/DC=mhf/DC=mhc
```

Domino converts the names in the AD field distinguishedName by itself. You don't need to add Notes names for AD users.

The only thing that did not work for me: if I put the user or group from AD in the Domino group, and then add the Domino group to ACL for a DB, the user from AD still does not have access to DB.